# How do I extract child registry keys from a dynamic HKEY_USERS\SID into a reg file, and replace the SID in the regfile using Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, sid

I am writing a backup/restore script for powershell that allows users backup and restore various settings before and after windows installations. One example includes `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3096151585-4241824952-1105149943-1008\SOFTWARE\7 Taskbar Tweaker\Options`

How do I save this key recursively as a reg file, just for example with `reg export <keyname> <filename> [/y]` or another export mechanism, without manually inputting the sid? The SID is dynamic on fresh installations, so I must also replace the SID in the reg file to ensure proper importation.

```
$User = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:UserName)
$sid = $User.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).value
```

The above snippet gives you the SID of the logged-in user. This when appended to the HKEY_USERS givs you the right path for that username.

```
New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
Get-Item "HKU:\${sid}"
```

This pulls the sid of the current user;

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\temp\test.reg").Replace("anoose","$sid"); [System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("c:\temp\test.reg", $content)
```

This replaces anoose with the current SID, but how do I use a regex pattern to replace an old SID with the current user sid?

I tried the following two regex strings which should locate SID `/^S-1-[0-59]-\d{2}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{8}-[1-9]\d{3}/` values, `/^S-1-[0-59]-\d{2}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{8}-[1-9]\d{3}/`, or `^S-\d-\d+-(\d+-){1,14}\d+$`, or `^S-\d-(\d+-){1,14}\d+$` or `S-\d-\d-\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+-\w+`, none of these appear to work in my script; ex, `$r = [regex] "/^S-1-[0-59]-\d{2}-\d{10}-\d{10}-\d{8}-[1-9]\d{3}/"`...

"Replace" tries to replace the regex pattern itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#get sid from username
$User = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($env:UserName)
$sid = $User.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).value
#set export filename
$filename = "$env:SystemDrive\Export\$($env:UserName).reg"
#key to export, without HIVE or SID e.g. SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
$key = "SOFTWARE\7 Taskbar Tweaker\Options"
#check whether the user hive is loaded
if (Test-Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$sid" -PathType Container) {
    #it is loaded, check the key
    if (Test-Path "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$sid\$key") {
        Write-Output "The specified key was found under: $env:UserName. Exporting..."
        & "$env:windir\system32\reg.exe" "EXPORT `"HKEY_USERS\$sid\$key`" `"$filename`" /y"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "The specified key does not exist under: $env:UserName"
    }
}
Else {
    #it isnt loaded, load it
    & "$env:windir\system32\reg.exe" "LOAD HKU\TEMP `"$env:SystemDrive\Users\$env:UserName\NTUSER.DAT`""
    #export the key if the key exists
    if (Test-Path "Registry::HKU\TEMP\$key") {
        Write-Output "The specified key was found under: $env:UserName. Exporting..."
        & "$env:windir\system32\reg.exe" "EXPORT `"HKU\TEMP\$key`" `"$filename`" /y"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "The specified key does not exist under: $env:UserName"
    }
    #unload it
    & "$env:windir\system32\reg.exe" "LOAD HKU\TEMP"
}
```